# Async/await, Task Parallel For complex process running FINE on while debugging but failed to run without

Tags: c#, async-await, out-of-memory, task-parallel-library

I am trying to execute a very complex operation parallely with TPL For. It has API calling with async/await and with selenium webdriver.

When I debug the application, it runs smoothly, but when I run it without debugger, it crashes shortly and following message shows.

```
{System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle rect, PixelFormat format)
   at Browser_Automation.Parser.CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section) in E:\Work\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX Automation\JSON\SuiteParser.cs:line 598
   at XXXXX.Parser.GetCaptchaById(IWebDriver driver, String id) in E:\Work\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXAutomation\JSON\SuiteParser.cs:line 577
   at Browser_Automation.Parser.<GetFirstCaptchaUrl>d__23.MoveNext() in E:\Work\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXAutomation\JSON\SuiteParser.cs:line 526
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Browser_Automation.Parser.<_Execute>d__27.MoveNext() in E:\Work\SupportKing\VisaBot\Browser Automation\JSON\SuiteParser.cs:line 646}
```

Here is the code, where it indicates the bitmap memory out ....

```
private string GetCaptchaById(IWebDriver driver, string id)
    {
        //Getting the image, which is in this case has a url as source.
        var captcha_image = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
        string resultBase64 = "";
        if (captcha_image != null)
        {

            try
            {
                //Deleting previous screenshot images from the folder
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(App.Directory.FullName + "\\ScreenshotImages");
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }


            var path1 = App.Directory.FullName + "\\ScreenshotImages\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";

            //Creating screenshot of the full web page and saving it to the path
            ITakesScreenshot ssdriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
            Screenshot tempImage = screenshot;
            tempImage.SaveAsFile(path1, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

            //Creating a rectangle of same size as the captcha
            Point point = captcha_image.Location;
            point.X = point.X;
            point.Y = point.Y;
            int width = captcha_image.Size.Width;
            int height = captcha_image.Size.Height;
            Rectangle section = new Rectangle(point, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));

            //Loding the full page image from the path
            Bitmap fullImg = new Bitmap(path1);

            //creating a new image as the same width height of the captcha
            Bitmap source = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

            //This is the final captcha image. We are croping the captcha image from the full image with location(X,Y) and size(W,H)
            Bitmap final_image = CropImage(fullImg, section);

           resultBase64 = ConvertBitmapToBase64(final_image);
            //final_image.Save(@"E:\\out.jpg");
        }

        return resultBase64;
    }
```

**And it is the line where its catching the error :**

```
Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
```

Comment: This question is unclear in it's current state. Are you sure you share same data between debug and release versions? Show the code where the exception occur. Show something that help us investigate the problem. Dumping exception without code and context gives nothing valuable to resolve issue.

Comment: @Mateusz Here is some code addeed

Comment: As @TheGeneral wrote in his answer. Try disposing all of your unused `Bitmap` objects. This should get rid of your exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of things:

1. Don't mix `Parallel.For` with async and await. It's not suited to work with the async and await pattern.
2. Your exception is most definitely caused by running out of GDI memory because you are not disposing all your `Bitmaps`.

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.  at
> System.Drawing.Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle rect, PixelFormat format)

Put all your bitmaps into a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Or call `Dispose` immediately after you have finished with them.

Comment: `Disposing all bitmaps` - does it mean, at the end of the method, I have to dispose the three bitmap I defined? or anything else?

Comment: I cannot avoid Parallel.For, And cannot avoid async await, as I am getting an api call in here. Can you suggest me better concept?

Comment: @AbdurRahim updated about dispose, I think your async is another question

Comment: :D Can I tag you with some other questions? Later?

Comment: I have an another error. searching to find the solution, it is also caught in the same mthod as above. THe mssage given in below comment.

Comment: `Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'E:\Work\SupportKing\VisaBot\Browser Automation\bin\Debug\Browser Automation.exe'.
Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x16dd323c, on thread 0x150c. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.`

Comment: @AbdurRahim you may need to ask another question with the appropriate details

Comment: Okay I will and tag you then.